# Pass lambda expression for Any() in Where() query as method parameter

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

I have the following theoretical method (Func param is probably not correct):

```
private void GenericMethod<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2, Func<T, bool> match) where T : class
{
   //I'm trying to avoid repeating this nearly identical functionality
   //For different lists types
   //var items = list1.Where(e => !list2.Any(f => f.SomeId == e.SomeId));

   //where match is f.SomeId == e.SomeId
   var items = list1.Where(e => list2.Any(match));

   ...
   ...
}
```

Is it possible to get this to work with relative ease - i.e. the actual call to the method is not so complex that it's as time consuming to write as it is to just repeat the code.

and if yes how do I pass in the "match" parameter when I call the method?

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: @TheGeneral I don't know how to structure the call to the method - as per the last part of the question. And I suspect the Func has to be something like Func<T, T,bool> or something

Comment: @the comments in the code clearly indicate the functionality I'm trying to pass in as a parameter. The point being that T may be any two lists of the same type - so where in one case e.SomeId == f.SomeId and in another it might be e.AnotherId == f.AnotherId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you should be able to do this

```
private void GenericMethod<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2, Func<T, T, bool> match)
{
   var items = list1.Where(e => !list2.Any(f => match(f,e)));   
}
```

Usage

```
GenericMethod(list1,list2, (l1,l2) => l1.bob == l2.bob);
```

<sub>***Note 1*** : In this simple example it's debatable if it's saving you much code or will look that much more satisfying. Also note, this is a quadratic time complexity, you might be better using `Except` that uses hashing with the appropriate ICompareable interface</sub>

<sub>***Note 2*** : This is quadratic time complexity, you might be better using `Except` that uses hashing with the appropriate ICompareable interface</sub>

<sub>***Note 3*** : If you want this done through EF, you will likely need to use an expression</sub>

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I needed thank you! As per your note - I'm reusing the match function 3 times within the method to extract the union, differences in both list 1 and 2 so this saves a lot of code - I'm also doing for many lists of different types and am tired of copy/pasting the same code with minor changes

Comment: @Rob take a note of the last note. you will get better performance out of except or something that uses hashing

Comment: Also List2 isn't a param in my real code it's pulled back from the DB as Entity using Set<T>()

Comment: you also made a good point about using Except and I looked at adding this in my code - but in reality the instances of the objects are not comparable because other properties with the object differ so I'd end up needing to specify a comparer for them or override their hash method which I don't want to do as I'm not comparing lists of more than a few lookup items as a time to add,update,delete from db